# GAE data download shows datastore_errors.BadRequestError

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to download data from my Google App Engine app, using [the official instructions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Setting_Up_remote_api)

Remote API is set up & I call:

```
appcfg.py download_data --application=appname --url=http://app.address.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=alldata.csv
```

The connection is established, I'm being asked for my e-mail & password, and then a long trace appears ending up with this:

> google.appengine.api.datastore_errors.BadRequestError: app s~appname cannot access app appname's data

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you literally passing "application=appname" or have you scrubbed your app ID from the command and the error?

Comment: I'm passing my app id :) But I found the solution already - the server name was wrong...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If using the high-replication datastore, change the value passed to --application from `appname` to `s~appname`.

Comment: This fixed my issue. Can you explain why passing s~ is necessary for high-replication datastore?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - as an URL I was giving my own app's domain name instead of the 1.appname.appspot.com.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, but when attempting to use the remote API from a custom script as opposed to  appcfg.py's bulk downloader.

This issue may have been addressed in more recent GAE SDK releases, but for various reasons I'm still using the older 1.7 release. I found the answer in this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4374

Basically, when calling ConfigureRemoteApi, don't specify the APP_ID argument (just pass None) and specify your app ID via the host argument, e.g. 'myapp-hrd.appspot.com'. ConfigureRemoteApi will figure out your app ID correctly and won't add the 's~' that causes this problem.