# Copying data from GAE to local data storage fails

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have followed all the instructions:

1) I downloaded it like this:

```
appcfg.py download_data -A s~myApp --url=https://myApp.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api/ --filename=data.csv
```

Note that according to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8026482/92153) I have to append `s~` to the app name, or I get the error message:`google.appengine.api.datastore_errors.BadRequestError: app s~myApp cannot access app myApp's data`

2) I have to add remote_api access to my app.yaml

```
- url: /remote_api
  script: google.appengine.ext.remote_api.handler.application
  login: admin
```

3) I have to run the local server and go to `http://localhost:8080/remote_api`. In there I enter the admin email for local env and set it as administrator.

4) I upload the csv to local data storage:

```
appcfg.py --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api/ --filename=data.csv upload_data src/
```

Unfortunately it fails now with this error message:

```
ApplicationError: ApplicationError: 1 app "dev~myApp" cannot access app "myApp"'s data
```

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself, you have to specify the dev application name, hope this helps others.

```
appcfg.py --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api/ --filename=data.csv upload_data -A dev~myApp src/
```