# How to download the local datastore into csv file?

Tags: google-app-engine, csv, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to download my local fixture data into a csv, to keep it safe.

I have tried [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470032/copying-data-from-gae-to-local-data-storage-fails) 6 months ago, with the only difference that I downloaded the data from a deployed appengine project, rather than downloading it from my local datastore.

However how could I download it from my local datastore?

```
appcfg.py download_data --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api/ --filename=data.csv --email=x@w.eu --application="dev~myApp"
```

I get the following error message:

```
03:37 PM Downloading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20140626.153708
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20140626.153708.sql3
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-results-20140626.153708.sql3
Password for x@w.eu:
[INFO    ] Connecting to localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api/
[ERROR   ] Unable to download kind stats for all-kinds download.
[ERROR   ] Kind stats are generated periodically by the appserver
[ERROR   ] Kind stats are not available on dev_appserver.
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to the dev admin console (probably "localhost:8000")
2. Go to Datastore Stats
3. Click Generate Stats

This error occurs because the dev app engine does not automatically generate datastore statistics. Instead you must perform the steps above to manually generate these statistics.