# Can't perform "upload_data" on localhost

Tags: google-app-engine

When performing `affcfg.py upload_data` on my localhost in order to use my production datastore data, it keeps asking me for credentials:

```
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20140730.185704
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20140730.185704.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/remote_api/
Please enter login credentials for 127.0.0.1
Email: test@example.com
Password for test@example.com: 
Invalid username or password.
Please enter login credentials for 127.0.0.1
```

What is this username/password combination? I don't see this documented anywhere on the App Engine documentation. I have tried other [solutions](http://littleq.logdown.com/posts/2014/03/19/right-way-to-download-app-engine-and-deploy-it-to-development-server) ([here also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470032/copying-data-from-gae-to-local-data-storage-fails)) to no avail. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you see this page? https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2440

Latest edit seem to recommend to use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce now, I'll let you know how it goes shortly.

Comment: Did something wrong earlier, fixed the problem, thanks! Reply below if you want to get an accepted answer.

Comment: Awesome! I was just about to ask you for a sample SQLlite file to test out. Happy to hear it fixed it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you see this page? code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2440 Latest edit seem to recommend to use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1