# Unable to download AppEngine datastore entities

Tags: google-app-engine

Based on other questions, I expected to be able to run the following command to get a dump of datastore entities for my app:

```
appcfg.py download_data --filename data.db .
```

(Here's the [`app.yaml`](https://github.com/danvk/oldnyc/blob/65e484a5a51b020035925ed2141896dab38a16a5/viewer/app.yaml) file in that directory.)

When I run that command, however, I get a long stack trace ending with a crypic error:

```
google.appengine.api.datastore_errors.BadRequestError: app s~old-nyc cannot access app old-nyc's data
```

I get this error even if I explicitly specify `--application=old-nyc`. If, as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997538/gae-data-download-shows-datastore-errors-badrequesterror), I specify `--application=s~old-nyc`, then I get this error:

```
[ERROR   ] Authentication Failed: Incorrect credentials or unsupported authentication type (e.g. OpenId).
```

What do I need to do to download my data?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `--application s~old-nyc` changed the default URL to `http://s~old-nyc.appengine.com` rather than `http://old-nyc.appengine.com`. To get the command to work, I also had to specify `--url http://old-nyc.appspot.com/remote_api`.

My full command was:

```
appcfg.py download_data --application s~old-nyc --url http://old-nyc.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename data.db
```

Comment: Not strictly related, but it may help others: while that command works, the sqlite3 database it produces isn't particularly useful. I wound up hacking on [this repo](https://github.com/gergelyorosz/gae-export-as-csv) to export my small database to a CSV file.